# System.MissingMethodException - CoreOptionsExtension.get_WarningsConfiguration()

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a .Net Core 2.2 project using SqlLite.

When I get to this line:

```
optionsBuilder.UseSqlite(@"Data Source=Data\Database.db");
```

I get:

> System.MissingMethodException: 'Method not found:
>   'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.WarningsConfiguration
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.CoreOptionsExtension.get_WarningsConfiguration()'.'

This is masking the real reason for the exception.

How can I fix this?  I assume this an issue somewhere with PDBs but I haven't yet found the solution.

Comment: Is there an inner exception?

Comment: If you override the `OnConfiguring` method, do you still have that error? Please show us other code where and how you are using this.

Comment: Do you have package : Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/?tabs=netcore-cli

Comment: @jdweng I have Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.Core package reference.

Comment: @RobertHarvey InnerException is null.

Comment: I will start this comment with I have never used .Net Core 2.2. However, I've run into similar errors using Selenium, and no matter how much it seems like it isn't the actual problem, there is something wrong with your reference to that method. I'm not saying that is the case here, but I would do a very thorough look at all of the basic problems. Do you have all of your libraries listed at the top? Is there something wrong with the way you constructed your object? Etc.

Comment: Try a clean build.  if the doesn't work open Solution Explorer and right click the reference for the SQL.Lite and select properties.  The check if file exists using pathname in the properties.